# Is there any way to duplicate the effects of PowerShell's Format-Table in C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, string-formatting

For reasons that are beyond the scope of this question, I have a PowerShell script that I have to convert to C#.  At one point it queries a database and pipes the result to `Format-Table`.

Here is [the implementation of the Format-Table cmdlet,](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/FormatAndOutput/common/BaseFormattingCommand.cs#L44) but the way the whole thing is written seems to require knowledge of PowerShell internals to make sense of.

Is there any existing system that can take an `IDataReader` and produce similar textual output?

Comment: The class is reader a Power Shell object which is a table.  Maybe this will help : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e91c0536-219f-4f4c-8356-f9386ce0eb3e/using-powershell-hash-table-values-in-c-code

Comment: CsvHelpers library maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at https://spectreconsole.net/widgets/table or if that is overkill for your application https://github.com/khalidabuhakmeh/ConsoleTables. You will have to wire up handling the results from IDataReader but should be trivial.